# Remove HTML tags in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to output, using a select statement, a column as a `varchar` but even though I convert the column to `varchar` it still outputs the html tags which I don't need the formatting/only the text is required. A big problem as well is I have no permission to create functions, even though I have seen several functions in this site that lets me create a function to fix this issue. I have limited permission to adding to our database but I have tried using temporary tables and CTE and I have permission to do those.

Right now I have used

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000),Message), CHAR(13),''), CHAR(10),'')
```

to try and convert the column from html to varchar and also remove the line breaks. It removes the line breaks which we don't want as well but the HTML tags such as `</font>,</o:p>,</p>,<br/>,&nbsp,` etc... are still showing up when I output to excel.

This is a test output im getting from the column:

```
<br /><h1><span style="font-size: x-small"><span style="font-family: Verdana"><u><i><b>test</b></i></u></span></span><u><i><b><br /></b></i></u></h1><div contenteditable="false"><a href="dsi://OpenPatientFolder.671">George C Test2</a>&nbsp;</div><br /><br />
```

The desired output:
test George C Test2

Comment: What process populates that varchar column?  What's the original data source?

Comment: It's from an internal e-mail system inside a electronic medical record program that allows formatting and adding hyperlinks.

Comment: Please provide a (reduced!) sample of your HTML. And please check your HTML, if it is XHTML (valid for XML).

Comment: added a test output of what im currently getting and a desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doable without the creation of a Table-Valued Function but is **NOT** pretty

Cross Apply B will "Clean the String"  this may require some maintenance.

Cross Apply C will Split/Parse the String, reduce it down to values between `> ... <` and then aggregate the string.

You may notice that char(13) and char(10) are NOT removed, but replaced with a space.  This is to ensure the replace is not destructive.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int, [Message] varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'<br /><h1><span style="font-size: x-small"><span style="font-family: Verdana"><u><i><b>test</b></i></u></span></span><u><i><b><br /></b></i></u></h1><div contenteditable="false"><a href="dsi://OpenPatientFolder.671">George C Test2</a>&nbsp;</div><br /><br />')
,(2,'<div><h1>This is the Title</hr><br >The content<br >Extra       Spaces will be trapped.  The End</div>')
,(3,'No HTML Tags')

Select A.id
      ,NewValue = ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(replace(TxtOnly,' ','†‡'),'‡†',''),'†‡',' ')))
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ( replace(
                        replace(
                        replace('<fake>'+[Message]+'</fake>'
                        ,char(13),' ')
                        ,char(10),' ') 
                        ,'&nbsp;',' ')   -- May want to add items like &mdash; as -  and &trade; as TM etc...
                      ) 
              ) B(CleanString)
 Cross Apply (
                Select TxtOnly = stuff((Select ' ' +RetVal 
                                         From  (
                                                Select RetSeq 
                                                      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex('<',RetVal+RetVal)-1)
                                                 From  (
                                                        Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
                                                              ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                                                        From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(CleanString,'>','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.'))) as A(x)
                                                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                                                       ) C1
                                                Where charindex('<',RetVal)>1
                                               ) C2
                                         Order By RetSeq
                                         For XML Path(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)')
                                        ,1,1,'') 
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
id  NewValue
1   test George C Test2
2   This is the Title Extra Spaces will be trapped. The End
3   No HTML Tags
```